# Etherlords - missing manual

Tags: ether-lords

Nival has been offering a free manual download (rtf) for [Etherlords](http://www.etherlords.com/etherlords1/usa/news/index.php). It used to be on ftp://ftp.nival.com/pub/etherlords1/, but the ftp appears to be down, probably permanently.

Will really appreciate if someone doesn't mind sharing a copy of the rtf. This is a kind of game that really makes you want one for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Replacementdocs.com](http://www.replacementdocs.com/download.php?view.464) offers the manual for download; but it's in .pdf format, unfortunately.

Comment: Doesn't matter, I wasn't going to edit it anyway. Thanks!